# Implementing Room with a viewmodel,how to get the return value of a query in DAO. instead of a List<> it just returns "CouroutineJob"

Tags: android, android-room

i am implementing Room with a vIewModel, my structure is the following

@DAO,@Entity,@Database,@Repository

```
@Entity(tableName="dx_table")
class dx_table(
@ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val naxme: String,
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "phone")
    val phone: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "passx")
    val passx: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "login_fx")
    val login_fx: String
)
@Dao
 interface dx_dao{

    @Query("SELECT * FROM dx_table")
   fun get_all():LiveData<List<dx_table>>

    @Insert
    suspend fun insertTrx(dx_table:dx_table)

    @Query("UPDATE dx_table SET login_fx =:login_fx where phone=:phonex")
    suspend fun insertFx(login_fx: String,phonex: String)


    @Query("SELECT * from dx_table where phone=:phonex")
    suspend fun get_name_px(phonex: String):List<dx_table>

    @Query("Delete from dx_table")
    suspend fun deleteAll()

    @Query("Select * from dx_table where login_fx=1")
    suspend fun selectFx():List<dx_table>


}

@Database(entities = arrayOf(dx_table::class), version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class DxDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun dxDao(): dx_dao

    companion object {
        // Singleton prevents multiple instances of database opening at the
        // same time.
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: DxDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): DxDatabase {
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if (tempInstance != null) {
                return tempInstance
            }
            synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    DxDatabase::class.java,
                    "dx_database"
                ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}




class dxRepository(private val dxDao: dx_dao ){


val k_d:LiveData<List<dx_table>> = dxDao.get_all()


    suspend fun insert_trx(dx_table: dx_table){

        dxDao.insertTrx(dx_table)

    }

    suspend fun insert_fx(login_fx: String,phonex: String) {
        dxDao.insertFx(login_fx,phonex)
    }


    suspend fun select_fx() {
        dxDao.selectFx()
     }

    suspend fun get_name_px(phonex: String) :List<dx_table> {

         return dxDao.get_name_px(phonex) as List<dx_table>

    }

}
```

The viewmodel is

```
class DxViewModel (application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {


    var repository: dxRepository

    var k_d: LiveData<List<dx_table>>


    init {
        // Gets reference to WordDao from WordRoomDatabase to construct
        // the correct WordRepository.
        val dxDao = DxDatabase.getDatabase(application).dxDao()
        repository = dxRepository(dxDao)
        k_d = repository.k_d

    }


    fun insert_trx(dxTable: dx_table) = viewModelScope.launch {

        repository.insert_trx(dxTable)

    }


    fun insert_fx(login_fx: String, phonex: String) = viewModelScope.launch {

        repository.insert_fx(login_fx, phonex)

    }


    fun select_fx() = viewModelScope.launch {

        repository.select_fx()


    }

    fun get_name_px(phonex: String) = viewModelScope.launch {


       repository.get_name_px(phonex)


    }
}
```

I can track the live data using observe,its not an issue, the problem i am facing is with the **get_name_px(phone)**

```
 var mView = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(DxViewModel::class.java)

var lm = mView.get_name_px(phone)
```

here **lm** seems to be **job** type , i need the return List , how do i get it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your viewModel function `select_fx()` return a job, because `launch` does not return result, so you have to either:

1) Use async and await

```
 fun get_name_px(phonex: String) = viewModelScope.async {
       repository.get_name_px(phonex)
    }.await()
```

2) Not use launch viewModel, use it in Activity/Fragment

```
suspend fun get_name_px(phonex: String) = repository.get_name_px(phonex)

class CardFragment : Fragment() {

    fun get() {

        // launch in Dispatchers.Main
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            var lm = mView.get_name_px(phone)
        }

        // launch in background thread
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            var lm = mView.get_name_px(phone)
        }
    }
}
```